# sorting issue with firstname(varchar2 datatype) in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a user table where I have column firstname with datatype `varchar2`.  When I execute simple select statement with an order by clause like below:

```
select * from Loginuser order by firstname
```

I am getting the result in the correct order format.  Names starts from `A` and continue following order by but there the last 3 records don't match with this criteria.

If I check out last 6 records having firstname as below:

```
Ying
Yogen
Yvet
alo
pal
Ângelo
```

So I don't know what is wrong with the last three records?

Comment: For the first part of your problem, you just need a case insensitive sort.  For the accented character, you might be able to sort using a certain collation where A with a hat sorts the same as the letter A.

Comment: Also, please show us your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using `ORDER BY` along with a binary collation:

```
SELECT *
FROM Loginuser
ORDER BY NLSSORT(firstname, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI')
```

From the Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm):

> BINARY_AI designates an accent-insensitive and case-insensitive binary sort.

Answer (score 4):

Tim Biegeleisen gave a solution as to how you can solve the problem. But to answer the question you asked:

> what is wrong with last three records?

`ORDER BY` on a `CHAR`/`VARCHAR2` column will sort by the character code of successive characters.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff0c7e/7)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT firstname,
       ASCII( firstname ),
       DUMP( firstname )
FROM   loginuser
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff0c7e/7/0)**:

```
| FIRSTNAME | ASCII(FIRSTNAME) |                          DUMP(FIRSTNAME) |
|-----------|------------------|------------------------------------------|
|      Ying |               89 | Typ=1 Len=4: 89,105,110,103              |
|     Yogen |               89 | Typ=1 Len=5: 89,111,103,101,110          |
|      Yvet |               89 | Typ=1 Len=4: 89,118,101,116              |
|       alo |               97 | Typ=1 Len=3: 97,108,111                  |
|       pal |              112 | Typ=1 Len=3: 112,97,108                  |
|    Ângelo |            50050 | Typ=1 Len=7: 195,130,110,103,101,108,111 |
```

From the `ASCII` column, you can see that `Y` has an character code of 89, `a` is `97`, `p` is 112 and `Â` is a 2-byte unicode character 50050 (or the bytes 195 and 130) and they are sorted in ascending numerical order of the character codes.

Another solution is to use `CONVERT` and `UPPER` or `LOWER`:

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT firstname,
       UPPER( CONVERT( firstname, 'US7ASCII' ) )
FROM   loginuser
ORDER BY UPPER( CONVERT( firstname, 'US7ASCII' ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff0c7e/7/1)**:

```
| FIRSTNAME | UPPER(CONVERT(FIRSTNAME,'US7ASCII')) |
|-----------|--------------------------------------|
|       alo |                                  ALO |
|    Ângelo |                               ANGELO |
|       pal |                                  PAL |
|      Ying |                                 YING |
|     Yogen |                                YOGEN |
|      Yvet |                                 YVET |
```